# Holomorphic function $f$ in an open disc implies $f$ has a primitive/antiderivative

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Specifically I've been given a hint to use Cauchy's results for rectangles and triangles. Here's my attempt at proving this:

Let $z_c$ be the center of the open disc $A := B(z_c, \delta)$ for some $\delta$ such that our $f$ is holomorphic in A

Since our A is an open disc, it is simply connected and thus line integrals are path independent.

Then define $F_{x,y}= \int_x^y f(w)\  dw$ where both x and y are in A.

Is this enough?

Edit: I'm quite confused with the hint. Why would I need to use Cauchy's theorem for this?

Comment: You're on the write track. It's more natural to define $F(z)$ to be the line integral from $z_c$ to $z$. Now, what problems do you need to handle? Well, you need to show that $F$ is holomorphic, and that $F'=f$. If you try to prove this, you wll very quickly encounter that you need some result on the curve integrals of holomorphic functions.

Comment: How can I show F is holomorphic? I tried forming a rectangle with the diagonal vertices $z_c$ and $z$, and a triangle that starts from $z_c$, goes to $z$ and back. Then I used Cauchy's results to deduce the contour integrals are both 0, and equated them together. However I don't even think this is useful.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou It is more natural to say $F(z)=\int_0^z f(w)dw$ doesn't depend on the chosen path, then use a straight curve from $z$ to $z+\epsilon$ in $F(z+\epsilon) - F(z)=\int_z^{z+\epsilon}f(w)dw=\int_z^{z+\epsilon}(f(z)+o(1))dw=\epsilon (f(z)+o(1))$ ie. $F'(z)=f(z)$

Comment: @reuns Not sure which part you're responding to, but the independence of path is exactly where you use the fact that closed curve integrals vanish right? As for my appeal to the Cauchy-Riemann equations below, I prefer this proof because it generalises to situations where you only happen to know that curve integrals vanish along particular shapes (for instance, equilateral triangles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $[z,w]$ denote the line segment from $z$ to $w$. Define $F(z)=\int_{[z_c,z]}f(w)\textrm{d}w$. Let's argue that $F$ is holomorphic on $B(z_c,\delta)$.

Indeed, let $z_0\in B(z_c,\delta)$ and note that for any $z$, since $f$ is holomorphic, $\int_{[z_c,z_0]\cup [z_0,z]\cup [z,z_c]} f(w)\textrm{d}w=0$, which implies that
$$
F(z)-F(z_0)=\int_{[z,z_0]} f(w)\textrm{d}w
$$
Fixing now $z=z_0+t$, for $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we can now apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to get that $F$ admits partial $\Re z$-derivatives and

$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \Re z}(z_0)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f(z_0+s)\textrm{d}s=f(z_0)
$$
Similarly, we get that

$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \Im z}(z_0)=if(z_0),
$$
which implies that $F$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Hence, $F$ is holomorphic and $F'=f$.